# React Native state getting empty after action REDUX_STORAGE_SAVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am new in react native and I am kind of stuck in redux. I am trying to fetch the vehicles from the api endpoint, I am using redux-saga, the request sent, successfully fetches the data and dispathes the FETCH_VEHICLE_SUCCESS action. and state gets updated in redux store. But after that an action(REDUX_STORAGE_SAVE as shown in the image below) is automatically triggered and it empties the state i.e vehicles(refer to the image below). Why is it happening?

I am using redux-logger for logging, as shown on the picture below the vehicles object gets empty.

[image]

> saga.js

```
function fetchVehicleCall() {
  console.log('here');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      RegisterHelper.fetchAllVehicles()
      .then(res => {
          console.log('now');
          resolve(res);
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}

function* fetchVehicleRequest() {
  while (true) {
    yield take(GET_VEHICLE_REQUEST);
    try {
      const response = yield call(fetchVehicleCall);
      yield put(fetchVehicleSuccess(response));
      console.log('SAGA FETCH SUCCESS: ', response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('SAGA FETCH ERR: ', err);
    }
  }
}


export default function* root() {
  yield fork(fetchVehicleRequest);
}
```

> actions.js

```
export function fetchVehicleSuccess(vehicles) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_VEHICLE_SUCCESS,
    vehicles,
  };
}
```

> reducer.js

```
case FETCH_VEHICLE_SUCCESS:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
      vehicles: action.vehicles,
   });
```

Comment: you don't need to use infinity loop in saga, use https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args instead, also provide implementation for REDUX_STORAGE_SAVE action and respective reducer

Comment: Ok. I'll try the same and come back to you.